# Default value for optional generic parameter in Swift function

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to give an optional generic parameter a default value?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T? = nil) -> Channel {

}

let myChannel = addChannel("myChannelName")
```

But I'm getting an error saying

`Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Is it just a case of what I'm trying to do being impossible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's impossible in the way you've done it. Given just the code above, what type is `T`? The compiler, as it says, can't figure it out (neither can I, and I assume you couldn't either because the data's not there).

The solution to the specific question is to overload rather than use defaults:

```
func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T?) -> Channel { ... }

func addChannel(name: String) -> Channel { ... }

let myChannel = addChannel("myChannelName")
```

But it raises the question of what you're doing here. You would think that `Channel` should be `Channel<T>`. Otherwise, what are you doing with `data`? Without resorting to `Any` (which you should strongly avoid), it's hard to see how your function can do anything but ignore `data`.

With `Channel<T>` you can just use a default, but you'd have to provide the type:

```
func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T? = nil) -> Channel<T> { ... }
let myChannel: Channel<Int> = addChannel("myChannelName")
```

Otherwise the compiler wouldn't know what kind of channel you're making.

(UPDATE ~ Swift 5.2)

Sometimes you'd like a default type for `T`. You can do that with an overload. For example, you might want the default type to be `Never`. In that case, you would add an overload like this:

```
func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T? = nil) -> Channel<T> { ... }
func addChannel(name: String) -> Channel<Never> { 
    addChannel(name: name, data: Optional<Never>.none)
}
```

With that, you can have a simpler call:

```
let myChannel = addChannel(name: "myChannelName") // Channel<Never>
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - I just misunderstood how to use generics. My use case was that `data` can be any type of Dictionary, Int or String, or it can be nil. Is the preferred way of doing that to make `data: AnyObject? = nil` and then perform checks for the type of data inside the function?

Comment: The preferred way to do that is not be "any type of Dictionary, Int, or String." Determine what type it really is. That may be a "Data" type that could contain any of those. You implement that as an enum with associated data. That way you can make sure you receive what you expect, not just "AnyObject". When you start getting AnyObject? into your system, things go badly quickly in my experience. Even discounting the design problem, the compiler hates it.

Comment: For more on Enumerations, which are a key type within Swift, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html.

Comment: And if you have to bridge to ObjC and cannot use associated data, you still should wrap this into a class that can be initialized with only the things you expect. Only use AnyObject when you literally mean "I don't care; send me anything at all."

Comment: How would it look with using an enum? I can't seem to get it working.

Update

No worries, think I've got it

Comment: Or not...not sure how to make the case statement work

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. While not being able to use the generic default traditionally — leaving the argument out completely — I prefer the below to implementing overloads:

```
let myChannel=addChannel("myChannelName", data: Optional<Any>.none)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of the existing answers so that I can both call the function without the optional argument and avoid implementing the function twice.

```swift
func addChannel(name: String) -> Channel {
    addChannel(name: name, data: Optional<Any>.nil)
}
func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T? = nil) -> Channel {
    ...
}
```

As mentioned above you should avoid `Any`. In my case I know that `T` is an `Encodable` so I use this:

```swift
struct DefaultEncodable: Encodable {}

func function1(name: String) {
    addChannel(name: name, data: Optional<DefaultEncodable>.nil)
}
func function1<T: Encodable>(name: String, data: T? = nil) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue while defining a complex function with a large number of generics, for which overloading would have resulted in an unmanageable number of variations. Here is the code:

```
struct Channel{
    //Your code here
}

class ChannelManager{
    static let typedNil : Int? = nil //<--- This is what eliminates the error "Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
    
    public static func addChannel<T>(name: String, data: T? = typedNil) -> Channel{
        //Your code here
        return Channel() //To demonstrate that code compiles
    }
}
```

By declaring `typedNil` in this manner and using it as a default parameter, the default still is `nil` as expected, but the compiler sees it as a `nil` `int` and so is able to infer the type, avoiding the requirement of adding additional protocol conformance to existing types, or requiring overloads. Note that declaring `typedNil` as `static`, otherwise compilation will fail with the error "Cannot use instance member 'typedNil' as a default parameter."