# Default property value for a property whose type is a generic type parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following struct:

```
struct Thing<VerticalOffsetRange: RangeExpression> {
    var verticalOffsetRange: VerticalOffsetRange
}
```

I'm using the type parameter `VerticalOffsetRange` because I'd like to accept both open ranges (`Range`) and closed ranges (`ClosedRange`). I cannot use `RangeExpression` directly as the type for the `verticalOffsetRange` property because it has associated type or self requirements.

Now I'd like to provide a default value for that property, so that when the struct is initialized with the default memberwise initializer, the `verticalOffsetRange` parameter is optional.

```
struct Thing<VerticalOffsetRange: RangeExpression> {
    var verticalOffsetRange: VerticalOffsetRange = 0..<2
    // BOOM: Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to specified type 'VerticalOffsetRange'
}
```

This does not compile (error shown in line with comment). I'm certain that the value `0..<2` does conform to the `RangeExpression` protocol because before adding the default value, the following code works.

```
let myThing = Thing(verticalOffsetRange: 0..<2)
```

How can I provide a default value for the `verticalOffsetRange` property?

Note: This is a simplified version of the code I'm actually trying to write. But I think this is the part I'm stuck on at the moment.

Comment: (I originally marked this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458160/default-value-for-optional-generic-parameter-in-swift-function, and it's close, but the actual solution is different and I can't find a closer match.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `verticalOffsetRange` parameter to be optional, you can add it as a specialized `init` that applies when the type can be inferred:

```
extension Thing where VerticalOffsetRange == Range<Int> {
    init() {
        self.verticalOffsetRange = 0..<2
    }
}
```

Then `Thing()` will implicitly mean a `Thing<Range<Int>>` with the value you'd like, if `Thing<Range<Int>>` is valid in the context.

Comment: With this approach, it seems like I can only get the default value when I initialize with no parameters (`Thing()`). In my actual code I have several other properties, and I'd really like to use the memberwise initializer for those properties. I don't see any way to do that without explicitly declaring all the initializer combinations.

Comment: [SE-0347 will remove the need for this extension](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-type-inference-from-default-expressions/55585) but it doesn't appear to permit memberwise initialization. You don't need "initializer combinations"—default values just become default arguments.

Comment: To restate Jessy's point, you shouldn't need all the combinations. You just need to add non-generic defaults to what you want in the extension. Can you give an example where that isn't working?